# Sparkline Jquery - any way to make sense of this to actually show accurately?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts

I'm using Sparkline for my application and I love the pie chart; however, I cannot get data to be represented accurately for nothing in this world. I know there is some equation I can use to get this correct, but it doesn't make any sense for me.

For example:

```
$("#data").sparkline([1,2], {
    type: 'pie',
    height: '140',
    sliceColors: ['#F5F5F5','#1ab394']
});
```

What I am trying to represent here is 1 out of 2 items, to show 50%. The second integer is basically my "total" number of items and the first is the number of items purchased. If you display this in Sparkline, however, the chart shows as 1(33%) and 2(66%). Perhaps this isn't the right kind of chart for displaying such data?

What's the best way to represent this?

Answer (score 0):

Make the following change. Change [1,2] to [1,1]. Basically, the percentages are calculated based on the value/total of values. for [1,2]. the percentage is 1/3 and 2/3. For [1,1], the percentage is 1/2 and 1/2 so 50%

```
$("#data").sparkline([1,1], {
    type: 'pie',
    height: '140',
    sliceColors: ['#F5F5F5','#1ab394']
});
```

Comment: I guess this isn't the right type of chart I'm looking for then. I wanted to be able to show both the total and the percentage, but this looks like this may be for something else.

Comment: can you elaborate, what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: For example, if 10 out of 20 products exist, I want to represent that in the pie chart by providing 10,20.